# How to serialize an object using javascript only (no Jquery)?

Tags: javascript, object, serialization, httpwebrequest

I have an object say image

```
        look : {
            name : "hello baby",
            tag_list : "hello",
            collection_id : 1,
            category_id : 1
        },
```

I want to serialize this object so that it can be sent via **POST / GET** request to the server. I cannot use JQUery for this purpose.

look[name]=hello

Comment: just pass `look` as data along with the ajax call (e.g. using jquery $.post)

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
var a = [];
for (var p in obj)
    a.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[p]));
var qstring = a.join("&");
```

Comment: nice use of push/join; otoh, encodeURICompenent->encodeURIComponent. This assumes plain objects with plain values...

Comment: @mplungjan In most cases you're right, but you may never know if a key contains chars like '&' or '='.

Comment: @tucuxi Yes, but common HTTP query strings are flat key/value arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Try using for..in loop. It gets each variable from object.

```
function serialize(obj)
{
     var serialized = "";
     for (variable in obj)
     {
        if(serialized != "") serialized += "&";
        serialized += variable + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[variable]);
     }
}
```

Comment: @RohanPrabhu No need for a GET/POST, Sahil would probably deal with plain objects.

Comment: will fail with functions and inherited properties

Comment: also, bad encoding. What about { hi : "this&will&break&everything" } ?

Comment: @MaxArt: What does this have to do with the request method? What is a 'plain' object? Do you mean flat hierarchy objects? And saying that, in my opinion is a risky assumption.

Comment: Unlikely OP wants to post functions to his server

Comment: It's just the basic concept. It should work fine with POJO objects with no nested objects. It can meet requirements as in question he shows example of flat hierarchy object.

Comment: @RohanPrabhu Sending data with a GET/POST is a matter of building a string out of a key/value flat collection. So, if Sahil has a more complex object, he probably has to rethink something.

Answer (score 0):

Code taken from http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/46827/Serialize-Object-in-Javascript

```
function serialize(obj)
    {
        var returnVal;
        if(obj != undefined){
        switch(obj.constructor)
        {
            case Array:
                var vArr="[";
                for(var i=0;i<obj.length;i++)
                {
                    if(i>0) vArr += ",";
                    vArr += serialize(obj[i]);
                }
                vArr += "]"
                return vArr;
            case String:
                returnVal = escape("'" + obj + "'");
                return returnVal;
            case Number:
                returnVal = isFinite(obj) ? obj.toString() : null;
                return returnVal;               
            case Date:
                returnVal = "#" + obj + "#";
                return returnVal;       
            default:
                if(typeof obj == "object"){
                    var vobj=[];
                    for(attr in obj)
                    {
                        if(typeof obj[attr] != "function")
                        {
                            vobj.push('"' + attr + '":' + serialize(obj[attr]));
                        }
                    }
                        if(vobj.length >0)
                            return "{" + vobj.join(",") + "}";
                        else
                            return "{}";
                }       
                else
                {
                    return obj.toString();
                }
        }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: You should avoid using `escape()` in URIs: http://xkr.us/articles/javascript/encode-compare/. Also, simple objects such as {a: 1, b: 2} will have no constructor

Comment: Numbers do have a constructor: `alert((1).constructor === Number)`. Only `null` and `undefined`, among the primitive entities, don't.

Answer (score 0):

For plain one dimensional objects, you can use

```
var ser ="";
for (var o in look) ser += "&"+o+"="+encodeURIComponent(look[o]);
alert(ser.substring(1));
```

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json.js), adds a stringify method to your objects, and a parseJSON method to your strings.

source: [JSON.org](http://json.org/)

Comment: Use https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js instead. Modifying Object.prototype should be avoided (and will happily break a lot of answers that use `for (var y in x)` without doing a hasOwnProperty next :-)

Answer (score 0):

Simply use:

```
var look = {
            name : "hello baby",
            tag_list : "hello",
            collection_id : 1,
            category_id : 1
        };

   var serialized_object = JSON.stringify(look);  // to serialize an object
   var deserialized_object = eval('('+ serialized_object + ')');  // to deserialize an object
```

Comment: Please use `JSON.parse` to parse JSON, not `eval`.